# How to get json data from another website in Flask?

Tags: python, json, flask

I want to make a website with Flask to show some data posted from another website such as [this one](https://api.github.com/users/runnable).In short,I want to list the data from that website.

Should I use this method: [`flask.Request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.get_json)?

I do not know how to get a Request object. Could you show me some demos about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Python 3 and Flask.

```
import requests

def get(url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url)
        return res.json()
    except:
        return False

data = get('http://example.com')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

> In short,I want to list the data from that website.

The accepted answer seem not use flask, so I'll add some:

```
from flask import jsonify, Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/runnable')
    return jsonify(r.json())
```

> Should I use this method: flask.Request.get_json()

No, it is for parsing the incoming json request data. No one is sending requests to you.

Comment: Sorry it seems I can only give one accepted answer.